# Changing text color for Input fields

Tags: color, customization, stylesheet

I try changing the color for the Input fields.  By going to `Format >> Text Color >> Orange` the color stays to the default value of blue?? For any other field, this works as expected, however.
This also seems to be the only reluctant one, since changing, say, the background color works fine?

Comment: `Style[InputField[1234], FontColor -> Red]`. Is this what you are after?

Comment: @AlbertRetey Well, maybe I misunderstood what Input fields are, but I assume that they are the "usual" Mathematica codes at least (obtained by simply starting typing in Mathematica or through Alt+9). when I try changing the color of the text from its default blue, nothing happens.

Comment: Patrick, use  `Preferences` under `Edit` menu; and  select the color you want under `Appearance >> SyntaxColoring >> Other`.

Comment: That is nice. Do these changes only affect the local notebook? Is there a way to implement this in a stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change `AutoStypeOptions` in a style sheet, you can add:

```
Cell[StyleData["Input"],
    AutoStyleOptions->{"UndefinedSymbolStyle" -> {FontColor -> RGBColor[1., 0., 0.]}}
]
```

to the style sheet, which will cause all undefined symbols to be colored red. Alternatively, you could turn off auto styles, in which case your format change will take affect:

```
Cell[StyleData["Input"],
    ShowAutoStyles->False
]
```